# Why is the sql_handle for the same session not consistent between sysprocesses and dm_exec_requests?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I was trying to figure out which SQL query made the blocks on the SQL Server 2012, the SQL handler value for the same SPID inquired by different command returns different values:

Query #1:

```
select * 
from sys.sysprocesses
```

with SPID = 281, returned the value of

```
"0x010006001838FB01D091A31B1602000000000000"
```

Query #2:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

with SPID = 281, returned the value of

```
"0x060006001838FB0100DFA2B21402000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Furthermore, the more important to me is that the return of SQL context inquiry command `Sql ( sys.dm_exec_sql_text{sql_handle_value} )`:

Query #1:

```
"0x010006001838FB01D091A31B1602000000000000"
```

context return is empty;

Query #2:

```
"0x060006001838FB0100DFA2B21402000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

context return is valid query record.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: given that sys.sysprocesses has been on the deprecation list for some time (though not fully covered as yet! (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891986-deprecation-of-sysprocesses-dmv-s-doesn-t-fully))  I would just use the value in sys.dm_exec_requests

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same thing

[`sys.dm_exec_requests`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> sql_handle    `varbinary(64)` Is a token that uniquely identifies the
>   batch or stored procedure that the query is part of. Is nullable.

[`sys.sysprocesses` (deprecated)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> sql_handle    `binary(20)` Represents the currently executing batch or object.
>
> Note This value is derived from the batch or memory address of the
>   object. **This value is not calculated by using the SQL Server
>   hash-based algorithm.**

They have different datatypes and are calculated differently. The (deprecated) function [`sys.fn_get_sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-sql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) accepts both formats though

```
SELECT spid, sql_handle, text 
FROM sysprocesses
cross apply  sys.fn_get_sql(sql_handle)

select * 
from sys.dm_exec_requests
cross apply  sys.fn_get_sql(sql_handle)
```

but you should be using the newer DMOs (`sys.dm_exec_requests` and `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`) not the deprecated ones

Comment: many thanks for your explainations; but for many of the circumstance, i use those commands aimed to exactly determine which SQL query makes the blocks listed in sp_who(2) outputs.